# jQuery - can you check to see if a class has another class?

Tags: jquery, class

I know that you can check to see if an id (or other selector) has a certain class:

```
$('#mydiv').hasClass('bar')
```

But can you check to see if a class also has another class? Like:

```
$('.myclass').hasClass('bar')
```

Just wondering?

Comment: Try and see, why shouldn't it work?

Comment: I vote to close "unclear what you're asking" just because there is no "OP is too lazy to test"... ;)

Comment: if you have multiple `.myclass` this will return true as long as one of them has `.bar`

Comment: ya it's easy to test, but googling this answer was even less work.  +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is trivial to test. See it working on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8V4Y/) (a great online tool for web developers).

```
<div id="mydiv" class="myclass bar">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
alert($('.myclass').hasClass('bar'))
```

Answer (score 9):

Or skip the check and just select the elements instead.

```
$('.myclass.bar')
```

If you need to check for existence:

```
$('.myclass.bar').length > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works

```
if ($('.myclass').hasClass('bar')) {
//do some thing 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
if($('.myclass').find('bar').length > 0)
   //Do you code
```

hope this helps you

Comment: will always be true. You need to check length

Answer (score 1):

A class cannot have another class, only an element (that you get with its selector) can have multiple classes.

In order to check if #mydiv which has the class bar also has the class foo you can write something like:

```
if( $('#mydiv.bar').hasClass('foo') ) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work

Read more about [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)